# Increase Force of a Solenoid

Tags: power-supply, solenoid, switching, mechanical

I tried to build a circuit that would allow me to push a washing machine's start button remotely using a solenoid as an actuator.

The solenoid is wired to a 9v battery which also powers an ESP8266 through LM7805 voltage regulator.

Unfortunately, after soldering all the components, I discovered that the soleniod does not produce enough force to actually push the button.

The solenoid I used has the following parameters (sellers ebay page):

```
Rated Voltage & Current DC 6V 0.15A
Power   3.4W
Action Form Push Pull Type
Force   
Stroke: 2mm 35g/0.08lb
Stroke: 1mm 80g/0.18lb
Power On Type   Intermittent 25%
Max Power On Time   1 Second
Body Size   20 x 12 x 11mm/0.8" x 0.5" x 0.4"(L*W*H)
Cable Length    5cm/2"
Material    Metal, Electronic Parts
Weight  14g
Package Content 1 x DC Solenoid Electromagnet
```

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhI8l2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I don't want to desolder anything. The solenoid and battery are connected with plugs into the board so I can replace them easily.

My question is: having these constraints, is there anything I can do to increase the force of the push?

Maybe I can replace the solenoid with a different one? Or plug something else instead of it? Can plugging different power source help?

Comment: Use a power source that can deliver more power than a 9V battery. 150 mA is actually quite a strain for that type of battery, which was designed for circuits that require 10-20 mA at most.

Comment: * I'ld suggest to measure the consumption that you currently have and you'll probably coerce Dave's comment.
* I am surprised that the coil is rated 6VDC and 0.15A which is under 1W while it is supposed to consume almost 4W?
* The 6V rated voltage may be compatible with the fact that the battery can't drive the load.
* If you have a 9V adapter that can deliver 0.15A, you can check if the circuit works with a better power source (and measure the characteristics).

Comment: Use large capacitor such as 68000uF in parallel to the battery might give enough current strength to do the job. However yr transistor may need to upgraded to low on-resistance MOSFET.

Comment: @DaveTweed What will be the effect of these suggestions on the LM7805 that is connected to the same power source?

Comment: @soosaisteven What will be the effect of the suggestion on the LM7805 that is connected to the same power source?

Comment: And what will be feeding the 7805? The same 9V battery? And you will driving the solenoid from the output of the 7805? In this case the solenoid will be weaker than it was earlier. If the 7805 will be powering yr microcontroller, it sounds for fine. But it's really very inefficient chip for voltage bucking. You will be loosing energy there. Go for switching buck regulator.

Comment: Your solenoid is listed as expecting 6V, and you're powering it from 9V; you're already overdriving it. Also, an 7805 outputs 5V, while esp8266s are designed for 3.3V, you're overdriving that part as well, and might end up destroying it. Consider paying closer attention to required voltages.

Comment: I hate to ask, is 2mm enough of a stroke length to activate the button?

Comment: What is the use of that diode parallel to the solenoid-coil

Comment: @user2332665 As I understand, the solenoid can generate electricity spikes in the reverse direction. The diode protects against this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a lever.

Presumably the button has much less travel than the solenoid, so you can put the solenoid at the and of a long rod and multiply the force.

[image]

Comment: assuming he got the space to place that and that the solenoid push far enough.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced a similar issue with a different application.

In my case, I was controlling a solenoid with an N-Channel Mosfet. Like you, I used a current limiting resistor for the transistor's gate (base in your case). Its value was 260 ohm, which caused the source to gate voltage to be around 2V, too close to the threshold voltage. Lowering into it to 50 ohm increased this to 4V, allowing the transistor to be "more open or conductive" if you will, thus allowing the solenoid to draw more current from the battery.

It may work for you too, just be cautious not to exceed base max current. Good luck!